# set increment using flatMap

Tags: scala

I have a mutuable set and assigning the values to it from input

`var set = scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]()
set ++= (in.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt))`

Input:
1 5

Actual Output:
1,5

Required Output:
1,2,3,4,5

If have used flatMap with condition, but got error. How to achieve this with flatMap

Comment: `If have used flatMap with condition, but got error.` Can you post what you tried and the  error exactly ?

Comment: If the input is only 2 values why should the output have 5 values? A `Set` only contains what you put in it (minus any duplicates).

Comment: why you are so obsessed with flatMap why do you want to use only flat map? as i can see you are giving 2 int in the input which are space separated and if you will split it it's going to give you List("1", "5") now what makes you think you can use flatMap on that?

Comment: It seems, that you simply misunderstood `flatMap` and now you have wrong expectations.

Comment: I perhaps you mean `Range` instead of `Set`.

Comment: if you want number from 1 to 5 you can use List.range(1 ,5) or val range = 1 until 5 toList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have always a String like '2 5' as Input:

The solution could look like:

```
def toSeq(value: String): Seq[Int] = {
  value.split(" ")
  .map(_.toInt).toList match {
    case x1::x2::_ => x1 to x2
    case other => Nil// handle Exception
  }
}
println(toSeq("1 5").toList)
```

Be aware that the input is not validated!